# Is there something like setXML() for MainDocumentPart

Tags: docx4j

The Class `MainDocumentPart` (or to be correct the inherited from `JaxbXmlPart`, but anyway...) of docx4j implements a method `getXML()` wich returns a `String` with the XML code.

Now my question is: Is there also something that works the other way round - so that I have a given `String` containing the XML code and be able to set the MainDocmentPart accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming MainDocumentPart mdp, an example would be:

```
    String openXML = "<w:document  xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" >"
                    + "<w:body>"
                            + "<w:p>"
                                    + "<w:r>"    
                                            + "<w:t>foo</w:t>"   
                                    + "</w:r>"    
                            + "</w:p>"
                    + "</w:body>"
            + "</w:document>";

Document document = (Document)XmlUtils.unmarshalString(openXML);

mdp.setContents(document );
```

You can also add content at specific locations in the content tree using unmarshalString.  To do that you typically get a reference to the parent object, by traversal or XPath usually.

Comment: splendid, that was exactly what I was looking for - many thanks!